# relation between different CDFs and expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider random variables $Y, X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$, if $F_{Y}(y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i F_{X_i}(y)$, where $\lambda_i \geq 0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i= 1$.

Can we prove $E[Y] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i E[X_i]$? or $\int_{-\infty}^{y}uf_{Y}(u)du = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i \int_{-\infty}^{y}vf_{X_i}(v)dv$

Answer (score 1):

In case if the pdf is defined and exists for all the random variables. Following proof works:
$$\
F_Y(y)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iF_{X_i}(y)\\
{d\over dy}F_Y(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i{d\over dy}F_{X_i}(y)\\
\implies f_Y(y)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if_{X_i}(y)\\
E[Y]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \times f_Y(y)\, dy= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y \times \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if_{X_i}(y)\, dy = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \times f_{X_i}(y)\, dy\\
\implies E[Y]=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iE[X_i]
$$

Comment: @Icy If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as the correct answer.